# use the name of JList in java for ListSelectionListener

Tags: java, swing, jlist, listselectionlistener

I have more than one `JList` elements that I want to use from (`ListSelectionListener`)for these `Lists`,  but I dont know how I can use from name of `Lists` in a (`valueChanged`).

**Code snippet**

```
 JList listBox1=new JList(listModel); 
 listbox1.setname("list1");
 listBox1.addListSelectionListener(this); 

 JList listBox2=new JList(listModel1);
 listbox2.setname("list2");
 listBox2.addListSelectionListener(this);


 @Override
public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
 }
```

Comment: Unless you have some reason to re-use the code block, in which case you shouldn't care about which list generated the event, you should consider using separate listeners

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
    JList list = (JList)e.getSource();
    String name = list.getName();
}
```